# Console log in inspect element

Tags: parameters, console.log, inspect-element

When I console.log the parameters of handleClick i get the message in inspect element (console section) this message.

**{
"dispatchConfig": null,
"_targetInst": null,
"nativeEvent": null,
"type": null,
"target": null,
"eventPhase": null,
"bubbles": null,
"cancelable": null,
"defaultPrevented": null,
"isTrusted": null,
"view": null,
"detail": null,
"screenX": null,
"screenY": null,
"clientX": null,
"clientY": null,
"pageX": null,
"pageY": null,
"ctrlKey": null,
"shiftKey": null,
"altKey": null,
"metaKey": null,
"button": null,
"buttons": null,
"_dispatchListeners": null,
"_dispatchInstances": null
}**

**Here is the code:**

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    orange: PropTypes.bool,
    wide: PropTypes.bool,
    clickHandler: PropTypes.func,
  };

  handleClick = (abc) => {
    this.props.clickHandler(this.props.name);
    console.log ( abc)
  
  };
  

  render() {
    const className = [
      "component-button",
      this.props.orange ? "orange" : "",
      this.props.wide ? "wide" : "",
    ];

    return (
    
      <div className={className.join(" ").trim()}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.name}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Why am I getting this message in console? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: you are not passing any parameter to the handleClick. please try like this {() => this.handleClick(abc)}

Comment: Can you add me on Instagram to ask you some questions, if you have time, please? I would appreciate it a lot.